# byref typed value cannot be used at this point

Tags: f#

Let's say we implement an interface from a C# library which involves simulation of multiple return values and which, starkly simplified, might look like this:

```
type IExternalCommand =
    abstract Execute : byref<string> -> bool
```

Let's say further that we fake the strange workings of an actual external command with the following expressions:

```
type MyResult = Ok | Error of string

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module MyResult =
    let toMyResult (message : byref<string>) = function
    | Ok -> true
    | Error msg -> message <- msg; false

let ok = { new IExternalCommand with
    member __.Execute(message) =
        MyResult.toMyResult &message Ok } // works

let error = { new IExternalCommand with
    member __.Execute(message) =
        MyResult.toMyResult &message <| Error "fail" }
//                           ^^^^^^^ FS0418 The byref typed value 'message' cannot be used at this point
```

I am aware of the section on Byref Safety Analysis in the [F# spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) but fail to see how this is applicable in this situation (except for the byref values may not be used in the member implementation of object expressions part, which is confusing). Also, it used to work in F# 3. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a `byref` type cannot be used as a type parameter - e.g. something like `List<byref<int>>` is prohibited.

When you try to call the function like this, technically `MyResult.toMyResult` is treated as an expression of type `FSarpFunc<byref<sting>, ...>`, to which you then apply one parameter, and then pass the result of that to the `<|` operator. A value of type `FSarpFunc<byref<sting>, ...>` cannot exist, so you get an error. Admittedly, the error message could be clearer.

In the first example this works because F# has a special case for when a function is applied to exactly as many parameters as there are in its declaration. This special case is kind of necessary for interacting with non-F# code - among other things, to deal with this particular case.

Personally I would recommend not to use mutable cells if at all possible, they're a prime source of fat, juicy bugs. But if you absolutely must have a mutable cell, you have two options.

Option 1 - don't use an operator to break up function application:

```
MyResult.toMyResult &message (Error "fail")
```

Option 2 - use `ref<'t>` instead:

```
let tmp = ref ""
MyResult.toMyResult tmp <| Error "fail"
message <- !tmp
```